Prove that $K_1\cap K_2$ is a splitting field over $F$ where $K_1$ and $K_2$ are splitting field over $F$.
Let $K_1 \cap K_2$ be finite extension of $F$ contained in the field $K$, assume both are splitting field over $F$. Prove that $K_1\cap K_2$ is a splitting field over $F$.
Let $g(x) \in F[x]$ be an irreducible polynomial with a root in $K_1 \cap K_2$. This means that $g$ has a root in $K_1$ and also a root in $K_2$. Since both $K_1$ and $K_2$ are splitting fields, they contains all roots of $g$ i.e. $g$ splits completely in $K_1$ and in $K_2$. Since we are working on UFD, then factorization of $g$ in $K_1$ and $K_2$ are same up to units and order. Hence, $g \in (K_1 \cap K_2) [x]$.
It shows that $K_1 \cap K_2$ is a splitting field over $F$.(*)
My question is about this sentence (*). Splitting field of a polynomial is the smallest subfield of $K$ containing all roots of polymomial. How do we know that there is a polynomial such that $K_1 \cap K_2$ is a smallest field containing roots of that polynomial?

See also this post.

One way to prove this is to use the equivalent conditions of normality of fields. Then use that a map being an automorphism on $K_1$ and $K_2$ implies that it is an automorphism on the intersection.

Let $K_1 \cap K_2 = F(\alpha_1, \ldots , \alpha_n)$. If $f_i$ is the irreducible polynomial of $\alpha_i$ over $F$ (for each $1 \leq i \leq n$), then $f = \prod_{i=1}^n f_i$ is the polynomial you are looking for (in other words, $K_1 \cap K_2$ is the splitting field of the polynomial $f$ over $F$). Also, in your question post, I think you are trying to say that the polynomial $g$ splits as a product of linear factors in $(K_1 \cap K_2)[x]$ (since trivially, it belongs to this ring, being an element of $F[x]$).
